discrete fourier transform network behaviour analysis
In discrete Fourier transform how we analyze and interpret the graph to check the network behavior
I made a graph in python but I didn't understand the graph and I have made graph on s2d_bytes,d2s_bytes,dst_port,flow_duration

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
